# Memory usage of timeseries - lists of {Integer32, Real32}

Tags: memory, time-series, packed-arrays

A list of `{Integer32, Real32}` items in *Mathematica* seems to use 12-times as much memory than the `C` equivalent array of structs. And it looks like it can't be stored in a packed array, due to the integer/real mix. Besides splitting the time-series into two lists, one of timestamps and the other of values, so that each one can be packed individually, is there any other strategy?

Also, *Mathematica* 9 has a new function – [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TemporalData.html). Is that more efficient than a simple list?

Comment: Mathematica's `AbsoluteTime` returns the [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is per default represented by a `Real`. Isn't it a possibility to use this?

Comment: @halirutan at least it's almost unix time: `unixTime[date___]:=AbsoluteTime[date] - AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1}]`

Comment: Hmm, the source is UNIX time, but Mathematica seems to convert them to `Integer` when I use the following function: `Epoch[timestamp_] = AbsoluteTime[{1970}] + timestamp`

Comment: How do you assert that an integer is represented by Integer32 in memory? As far as I can tell, you have no control on that.

Comment: @Hector I don't, I just load them using `BinaryReadList` using `{Integer32, Real32}`. Even if Mathematica uses 64-bit ints/floats, there is still a 6x overhead over C.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what seems to be the problem.

```
Module[{fn = "D:\\Temp\\exp.mx", lt = Transpose@{Range[10], N[Range[10]/3]}, at}, 
 BinaryWrite[fn, lt, {"Integer32", "Real32"}]; Close@fn; 
 Print[FileByteCount@fn]; 
 Print[at = BinaryReadList[fn, {"Integer32", "Real32"}, 10]]; 
 Print[lt];
 at - lt]
```

That file is as packaged as it can be; and, besides rounding errors, the information is recovered.

As for the contents in memory, you do not have control over those. I do not think Mathematica uses 64-bits integers but as intermediate objects. Otherwise, it would not be able to make arbitrary precision arithmetic. For example, you can fit $2^{30}$ in a 32-bit integer and store in disk as such. Once loaded to memory, Mathematica has no problem finding $(2^{30})^5$, which cannot fit in a machine-size integer. The 12x overhead space is the price we pay for the *polymorphism* that Mathematica gives.

Comment: I was asking about in memory usage, not on disk. `ByteCount[ts]` shows 12x overhead